# Can I use "The sun is falling on me" while describing that there is heat?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, sentence-usage

Can I use the above mentioned sentence to indicate that the sun rays are falling on me? Or is there any proper sentence to express it?

Comment: The OP just wants to describe *the heat* and not specific to the case of he himself I guess.

Comment: @MaulikV I suppose that you might understand the OP better than me. I'm guessing that "the sun is falling on me" is a figurative phrase for the heat in your first language, perhaps?

Comment: @DamkerngT. Not like that! I felt that the OP is asking *while describing the heat out there* as in the title, in general. Had it been *he feeling a lot of heat*, all the *personalized* phrases could have been proper. Maybe, the OP did not intend it but it draws a sharp line between describing the heat *in general* or just for the asker.

Comment: @Damkerng I would particular avoid your first alternative.  I think you're accidentally using an idiom you don't intend to.

Comment: @snailboat Or does it simply mean "do not wait until tomorrow"?

Comment: Some other possible alternatives: *the sun beats down on me, the sun warms me, the sun hits me with its warmth, sunshine is bathing me, sunshine is hanging over me.*

Answer (score 2):

> *The sun is falling on me* is certainly incorrect. If the sun falls on us, we burn in less than a nanosecond!

The better adjective is *intense sun rays*. Some months back, the [news](http://www.theatlanticcities.com/design/2013/09/can-reflective-buildings-produce-death-rays-be-prevented/6758/) that drew everybody's attention mentions it.

> That's what happened to London motorist Martin Lindsay, who told the BBC that the wing mirror and badge portions of his Jaguar had melted due to intense sun rays reflecting off the Walkie Talkie tower.

[Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/intense?q=intense) explains *intense (v)*:

> Intense (adj): of extreme force, degree, or strength as in *the heat is intense*.

There's no need to mention **you** in this context. When the heat is intense, it affects everyone. So, simply to answer your question.

> **The heat is intense outside.**

Comment: That's not the OED.  Oxford makes more than one dictionary.

Comment: @snailboat What should I write then? Online ODs?

Comment: Okay, since we are not sure about the term, the anchor text will help the reader to take to the reference online.

Answer (score 2):

There are the less techical and more poetic forms:

I was bathed in sunlight. I was sun drenched. I basked in the sunlight,

I felt the sun on my face/skin. The sun warmed my skin.

I was sun-kissed.

It real can go on like this for a while. Our relationship with the light of the sun is a long and complex one, so there are many pharses used to describe it.

Comment: can you use present tense in the above sentences,as i asked the sun is falling on me,is present

Answer (score 1):

One idiom is “the sun is **beating down** on me” (for oppressively hot or burning sunshine).

To describe that the light falling on you, without any mention of heat, you could say “the sun**shine** is falling on me” or “the sun**light** is...”.  But it sounds incomplete, why is the sunlight significant?  “The sunlight is falling on me, and I am getting hot” would be more meaningful.

It would be more common to say something like “I am getting hot in the sun”.  In this case “in the sun” would be understood to mean “exposed to the sunlight”; you're not actually inside the sun.

If there is not too much heat, you might say “the sun is warming me”.

If you're talking about a saying where there is strong ambient heat (not necessarily from hot sunshine), a native English speaker would more liken it to being in an oven, rather than falling into the sun:

- “It's like an oven out here!”
- “I'm baking”
- “This heat is like a furnace.”